# Matplotlib interfering with PyQt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a situation where after displaying a dialogue box, setting parameters, then handling a callback for a button click that closes the dialogue and returns the values to be used for plotting in matplotlib. The issue is that combobox widgets will stay visible, sometimes the dialogue box will stay visible, etc. and interfering with plots.

Here's a reproducible example of the issue. I modified one of the PyQt examples (02 PyQt Widgets) and added a some matplotlib plotting functions. When you run the script and choose one of the options of the combobox (in the upper left part of the GUI) the choices will remain visible (please refer to the screen shots).

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDateTime, Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QComboBox, QDateTimeEdit,
QDial, QDialog, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,
QProgressBar, QPushButton, QRadioButton, QScrollBar, QSizePolicy,
QSlider, QSpinBox, QStyleFactory, QTableWidget, QTabWidget, QTextEdit,
QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import sys
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import time, sleep, strftime, gmtime

class WidgetGallery(QDialog):
def init(self, parent=None):
super(WidgetGallery, self).init(parent)

    self.originalPalette = QApplication.palette()

    styleComboBox = QComboBox()
    styleComboBox.addItems(QStyleFactory.keys())

    styleLabel = QLabel("&Style:")
    styleLabel.setBuddy(styleComboBox)

    self.useStylePaletteCheckBox = QCheckBox("&Use style's standard palette")
    self.useStylePaletteCheckBox.setChecked(True)

    disableWidgetsCheckBox = QCheckBox("&Disable widgets")

    self.createTopLeftGroupBox()
    self.createTopRightGroupBox()
    self.createBottomLeftTabWidget()
    self.createBottomRightGroupBox()
    self.createProgressBar()

    styleComboBox.activated[str].connect(self.changeStyle)
    self.useStylePaletteCheckBox.toggled.connect(self.changePalette)
    disableWidgetsCheckBox.toggled.connect(self.topLeftGroupBox.setDisabled)
    disableWidgetsCheckBox.toggled.connect(self.topRightGroupBox.setDisabled)
    disableWidgetsCheckBox.toggled.connect(self.bottomLeftTabWidget.setDisabled)
    disableWidgetsCheckBox.toggled.connect(self.bottomRightGroupBox.setDisabled)

    topLayout = QHBoxLayout()
    topLayout.addWidget(styleLabel)
    topLayout.addWidget(styleComboBox)
    topLayout.addStretch(1)
    topLayout.addWidget(self.useStylePaletteCheckBox)
    topLayout.addWidget(disableWidgetsCheckBox)

    mainLayout = QGridLayout()
    mainLayout.addLayout(topLayout, 0, 0, 1, 2)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.topLeftGroupBox, 1, 0)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.topRightGroupBox, 1, 1)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.bottomLeftTabWidget, 2, 0)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.bottomRightGroupBox, 2, 1)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar, 3, 0, 1, 2)
    mainLayout.setRowStretch(1, 1)
    mainLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
    mainLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
    mainLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
    self.setLayout(mainLayout)
    self.setWindowTitle("Styles")
    self.changeStyle('Windows')

def on_button_clicked(self):
    alert = QMessageBox()
    alert.setText('You clicked the button!')

    self.button_state = self.radioButton1.isChecked()
    print("self.button_state ", self.button_state)

    alert.exec_()
    sleep(1)

    self.accept()
self.done(0)
self.close()
generate_plots()
def changeStyle(self, styleName):
    QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create(styleName))
    self.changePalette()

def changePalette(self):
    if (self.useStylePaletteCheckBox.isChecked()):
        QApplication.setPalette(QApplication.style().standardPalette())
    else:
        QApplication.setPalette(self.originalPalette)

def advanceProgressBar(self):
    curVal = self.progressBar.value()
    maxVal = self.progressBar.maximum()
    self.progressBar.setValue(curVal + (maxVal - curVal) / 100)
def createTopLeftGroupBox(self):
    self.topLeftGroupBox = QGroupBox("Group 1")
    self.radioButton1 = QRadioButton("Radio button 1")
    radioButton2 = QRadioButton("Radio button 2")
    radioButton3 = QRadioButton("Radio button 3")
    self.radioButton1.setChecked(True)
    checkBox = QCheckBox("Tri-state check box")
    checkBox.setTristate(True)
    checkBox.setCheckState(Qt.PartiallyChecked)
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(self.radioButton1)
    layout.addWidget(radioButton2)
    layout.addWidget(radioButton3)
    layout.addWidget(checkBox)
    layout.addStretch(1)
    self.topLeftGroupBox.setLayout(layout)    

def createTopRightGroupBox(self):
    self.topRightGroupBox = QGroupBox("Group 2")

    defaultPushButton = QPushButton("Default Push Button")
    defaultPushButton.setDefault(True)
    togglePushButton = QPushButton("Toggle Push Button")
    togglePushButton.setCheckable(True)
    togglePushButton.setChecked(True)
    flatPushButton = QPushButton("Flat Push Button")
    flatPushButton.setFlat(True)
    button = QPushButton('Click This One')
    button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(button)
    layout.addWidget(defaultPushButton)
    layout.addWidget(togglePushButton)
    layout.addWidget(flatPushButton)
    layout.addStretch(1)
    self.topRightGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

def createBottomLeftTabWidget(self):
    self.bottomLeftTabWidget = QTabWidget()
    self.bottomLeftTabWidget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred,
            QSizePolicy.Ignored)

    tab1 = QWidget()
    tableWidget = QTableWidget(10, 10)
    tab1hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    tab1hbox.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
    tab1hbox.addWidget(tableWidget)
    tab1.setLayout(tab1hbox)
    tab2 = QWidget()
    textEdit = QTextEdit()
    textEdit.setPlainText("Twinkle, twinkle, little star,\n"
                          "How I wonder what you are.\n" 
                          "Up above the world so high,\n"
                          "Like a diamond in the sky.\n"
                          "Twinkle, twinkle, little star,\n" 
                          "How I wonder what you are!\n")

    tab2hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    tab2hbox.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
    tab2hbox.addWidget(textEdit)
    tab2.setLayout(tab2hbox)

    self.bottomLeftTabWidget.addTab(tab1, "&Table")
    self.bottomLeftTabWidget.addTab(tab2, "Text &Edit")

def createBottomRightGroupBox(self):
    self.bottomRightGroupBox = QGroupBox("Group 3")
    self.bottomRightGroupBox.setCheckable(True)
    self.bottomRightGroupBox.setChecked(True)

    lineEdit = QLineEdit('s3cRe7')
    lineEdit.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
    spinBox = QSpinBox(self.bottomRightGroupBox)
    spinBox.setValue(50)
    dateTimeEdit = QDateTimeEdit(self.bottomRightGroupBox)
    dateTimeEdit.setDateTime(QDateTime.currentDateTime())
    slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self.bottomRightGroupBox)
    slider.setValue(40)
    scrollBar = QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal, self.bottomRightGroupBox)
    scrollBar.setValue(60)
    dial = QDial(self.bottomRightGroupBox)
    dial.setValue(30)
    dial.setNotchesVisible(True)

    layout = QGridLayout()
    layout.addWidget(lineEdit, 0, 0, 1, 2)
    layout.addWidget(spinBox, 1, 0, 1, 2)
    layout.addWidget(dateTimeEdit, 2, 0, 1, 2)
    layout.addWidget(slider, 3, 0)
    layout.addWidget(scrollBar, 4, 0)
    layout.addWidget(dial, 3, 1, 2, 1)
    layout.setRowStretch(5, 1)
    self.bottomRightGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

def createProgressBar(self):
    self.progressBar = QProgressBar()
    self.progressBar.setRange(0, 10000)
    self.progressBar.setValue(0)

    timer = QTimer(self)
    timer.timeout.connect(self.advanceProgressBar)
    timer.start(1000)
def plot_data(df, title, fig_num):
FIGURE_SIZE = (8, 6)
df_len = len(df)
x_series = np.arange(0, df_len)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, num=fig_num, figsize=FIGURE_SIZE, 
                dpi=72, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k', sharex=True, sharey=False, 
                    gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.25}, tight_layout=False)

plt.suptitle('Plot Some Data', fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
plt_axes = plt.gca()
plt_axes.set_ylim(-10.0, 10.0)

axs[0].plot(x_series, df['data1'], alpha=0.8, ms=1, color='b', label='Data 1')  
axs[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10.))
axs[0].xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10./5.))
axs[0].set(title=title, ylabel="Amp") 

axs[1].plot(x_series, df['data2'], alpha=0.8, ms=1, color='b', label='Data 2')  
axs[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10.))
axs[1].xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10./5.))
axs[1].set(title=title, ylabel="Amp") 
plt.savefig('data_plot.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()  
plt.close()
def generate_plots():

data_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'data1': {17384: 98125, 2680: 98107, 722: 98005, 18754: 98109, 14554: 98155}, 
        'data2': {17384: 1.5, 2680: 0.75, 722: 3.25, 18754: 1.0, 14554: 2.5}, 
        'data3': {17384: 1650, 2680: 3700, 722: 51836, 18754: 2640, 14554: 9603}, 
        'data4': {17384: 2, 2680: 2, 722: 4, 18754: 2, 14554: 4}, 
        'data4': {17384: 1430, 2680: 1440, 722: 4670, 18754: 1130, 14554: 3180}, 
        'data5': {17384: 3.0, 2680: 1.0, 722: 2.0, 18754: 1.0, 14554: 2.0}
        })
print (data_df)

plot_data(data_df, 'data plot', 30)
def main(date_time_now):

print("main() - date_time_now: ", date_time_now)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
gallery = WidgetGallery()
gallery.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
app.exec_()
app.quit() 

print("main(): gallery.button_state: ", gallery.button_state)
generate_plots()
if name == 'main':

date_time_now = strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S', gmtime())
main(date_time_now)
```

[image: The PyQt example]

[image: After clicking the button and calling the plotting code.]

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered on the PyQt forums.

[Here's the link to the answer](https://forum.qt.io/topic/109552/matplotlib-interfering-with-pyqt/3)

> matplotlib has also a Qt based backend so these two might interfere
>   with each other. What I would suggest is that you use directly the
>   classes of that backend to integrate matplotlib with your Qt
>   Application.

I only had to add a this to my script and it works great.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```